# FOR XML query with lookup texual values

Tags: sql, xml, azure-sql-database, lookup-tables

I'm trying to find solution for this;
on Azure SQL Database in the main (facts) table I have

```
category_1_id category_2_id category_3_id
------------------------------------------
1000          2000          3001
1000          2000          3002
```

and second table is denormalized and need to stay like that with structure

```
cat_1_id cat_2_id cat_3_id  cat_1_name cat_2_name cat_3_name 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1000     2000     3001      Name1       Name2       Title1
1000     2000     3002      Name1       Name2       Title2
```

and I need to do export in XML from main table with textual values based on category id from all three categorie names in second table. Query FOR XML is done, but with numeric ID's values.

In second table there is no primary key and no relations, and I'm not sure can I have any relationship.. that needs to work like lookup.

Any ideas?

### Copy from an answer given by the OP which shouldn't be an answer:

Output is now like this

```
<category_1_id>1000</category_1_id>
<category_2_id>2000</category_2_id>
<category_3_id>3001</category_3_id>
```

And need to be

```
<category_1_id>Name1</category_1_id>
<category_2_id>Name2</category_2_id>
<category_3_id>Name3</category_3_id>
```

Comment: Not really clear for me... Please show the expected output!

Comment: @Shnugo thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest: This design is awfull. If you see the slightest chance to change this, you should really go for normalisation.

Anyhow, this can be done (but I'm not sure if I really understand your needs)...

I start with two declared table variables, to *mock-up* your scenario:

```
DECLARE @mainTable TABLE(category_1_id INT,category_2_id INT,category_3_id INT)
INSERT INTO @mainTable VALUES (1000,2000,3001);

 DECLARE @catalog TABLE(cat_1_id INT,cat_2_id INT, cat_3_id INT,  cat_1_name VARCHAR(100),cat_2_name VARCHAR(100), cat_3_name VARCHAR(100));
 INSERT INTO @catalog VALUES
 (1000,2000,3001,'Name1','Name2','Title1')
,(1000,2000,3002,'Name1','Name2','Title2');
```

The first approach uses three `TOP 1` sub-selects

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       (SELECT TOP 1 c.cat_1_name FROM @catalog AS c WHERE c.cat_1_id=m.category_1_id) AS category_1_id
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 c.cat_2_name FROM @catalog AS c WHERE c.cat_2_id=m.category_2_id) AS category_2_id 
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 c.cat_3_name FROM @catalog AS c WHERE c.cat_3_id=m.category_3_id) AS category_3_id 
FROM @mainTable AS m
FOR XML PATH('');
```

The second approach uses `VALUES` to create a derived table of the second table with an id and the name each in its own row (`unpivot`). This table can be joined to the main table's columns.

```
WITH CatalogValues AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT UnpivotedCatalog.*
    FROM @catalog AS c
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(c.cat_1_id,c.cat_1_name)
                     ,(c.cat_2_id,c.cat_2_name)
                     ,(c.cat_3_id,c.cat_3_name)) AS UnpivotedCatalog(id,name)

)
SELECT DISTINCT
       cv1.name AS category_1_id
      ,cv2.name AS category_2_id 
      ,cv3.name AS category_3_id 
FROM @mainTable AS m
LEFT JOIN CatalogValues AS cv1 ON m.category_1_id=cv1.id
LEFT JOIN CatalogValues AS cv2 ON m.category_2_id=cv2.id
LEFT JOIN CatalogValues AS cv3 ON m.category_3_id=cv3.id
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The result is the same for both cases:

```
<category_1_id>Name1</category_1_id>
<category_2_id>Name2</category_2_id>
<category_3_id>Title1</category_3_id>
```

Comment: Dear @Shnugo I want apologize for late response and I appreciate your effort. I was looking your example, but decide that I need to change design first. Second approach seams maybe more adjusted to project needs, later today or tomorrow I will try to complete example and write (or ask for) final solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I continue with this task, I run into another problem.. if someone have some time to check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163658/ms-sql-db-design-help

Thank you